# Magento: Opening System->Configuration->Inventory Gives Error

Tags: magento-1.8

When I try to open `System=>Configuration=>Invengory` it gives following error.
`There has been an error processing your request`

below is the error log in report file

```
a:5:{i:0;s:97:"Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_catalog_inventory_managestock";i:1;s:1704:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\System\ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:108:"/my_store/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/cataloginventory/key/b544589d13d839efa67ab5845e86e613/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/my_store/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I have tried by disabling all the extensions i have installed but still no success,

Please guide me if anyone have any idea on what goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

found an answer,

thanks to amit bera,

the answer is at this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62911/opening-system-configuration-inventory-gives-error

As per your, you issue has been rise for  backend model not available for any particular dropdown or multiselect option. The backend model class is

`Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Catalog_Inventory_Managestock`

and file location is `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Catalog/Inventory/Managestock.php` and this file missing at your instance.That why it create issue.

May be your magento does not install properly.